# Odd bug in my jQuery seems to prevent an event from firing

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax request as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/logical_interface/delete',
    context: this, // had to add this to get the line in the success function to work, never used it before nor do I understand why it works
    data: 'id=' + id,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // jQuery(this).parent().html('processing...');
        // if this line is uncommented then the DOM will be updated correctly
        // but the snippet in the success function won't fire but the delete
        // is still executed on the server side
        // the page is then stuck with the 'processing' text
    },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery(this).closest('tr').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffc6be' }, 'fast').hide('slow');
    }

});
```

**Update**

Server side code is simply the following Rails method:

```
def delete
  @logical_interface = LogicalInterface.find(params[:id])
  @logical_interface.destroy
  render :text => '1' // which is what I get in console.log
end
```

Comment: ...And? What happens?

Comment: Is `jQuery(this).closest('tr')` what you think it is? What happens if you add `console.log(data);` after that line - anything in the log?

Comment: the element's (`td`) html is updated with `processing` but the animation to remove the entire row in the `success` callback doesn't fire

Comment: Add a failure handler to see if the response is failing for some reason. You could also add some `console.log` statements to your success handler to make sure `this` is what you expect.

Comment: if I add a `console.log` after the `closest` line then I get what I expect. For some reason if I add that one line it stops the animation from firing.

Comment: If your server side does something, but the success doesn't fire, then that means something is causing it to return failure, probably a bug after your server side code finishes deleting.  Can we see the server side code?

Comment: @user2532739 the success fires if I don't execute the line in the 'beforeSend` function though. Will update question with server side code though

Comment: might be because you overwrote your current element when you use `jQuery(this).parent().html('processing...');`

Comment: @user2532739 in fact, success must be firing in both cases since the `console.log` works regardless of the `beforeSend` snippet or not.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I think you are right, if I just simply hide it then it all works fine :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the reason your success may not work is because you deleted the $(this) node.

What you are doing in your beforeSend function is going up one level and replacing **ALL** HTML with "processing...". This in turn deleted your reference point `jQuery(this)` from the DOM before the success case is reached. if `jQuery(this)` is removed then nothing happens (obvious).

Instead of overwriting the entire html with Processing, may i suggest you have a single element hidden until you trigger the ajax and show it beforeSend and hide it with the complete function.